# Gstreamer glimagesink set render-rectangle property

Tags: c++, gstreamer

I am trying to display gstreamer video on a particular portion of an OpenGL window in Windows 10 platform using c++.

Here is my pipeline :

```
appsink = gst_element_factory_make ("glimagesink", "videosink0");

gst_element_link_many(videosrc, vvideo_queue, rtpdecoder, h264decoder, videoconvert, appsink, NULL);
```

The video is getting overlayed on the entire OpenGL window. My requirement is to display gstreamer video on a particular portion of an OpenGL window.

I tried two approaches for it :

1. Set the value for "render-rectangle" property of glimagesink.

g_object_set(appsink, "render-rectangle", &new_dimensions, NULL)

g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT(appsink), "render-rectangle", &new_dimensions)

I tried g_object_set and g_object_set_property both but my program is crashing without any error or exception. What could be the solution for this issue?

2. I used the gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle() function

None of these approaches are making any change in the output.

Is there any other approach to render the video on a particular portion of an OpenGL window.

First approach :

```
// Create a GValue for xpos
GValue xpos = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init(&xpos, G_TYPE_INT);
g_value_set_int(&xpos, 30);

// Create a GValue for ypos
GValue ypos = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init(&ypos, G_TYPE_INT);
g_value_set_int(&ypos, 30);

// Create a GValue for width
GValue width = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init(&width, G_TYPE_INT);
g_value_set_int(&width, 30);

// Create a GValue for height
GValue height = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init(&height, G_TYPE_INT);
g_value_set_int(&height, 30);

// Create the GstValueArray
GValue new_dimensions = G_VALUE_INIT;
g_value_init(&new_dimensions, GST_TYPE_ARRAY);
gst_value_array_append_value(&new_dimensions, &width);
gst_value_array_append_value(&new_dimensions, &height);
gst_value_array_append_value(&new_dimensions, &xpos);
gst_value_array_append_value(&new_dimensions, &ypos);

g_object_set(appsink, "render-rectangle", &new_dimensions, NULL);
//g_object_set_property (G_OBJECT(appsink), "render-rectangle",&new_dimensions);
```

Second approach:

```
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY (appsink), main_window_id);  
    
    if(!gst_video_overlay_set_render_rectangle(overlay_element, 30, 30, 30, 30))
    {
      std::cout<<"\n\n\n Could not resize\n\n\n";
    }
    

    gst_video_overlay_expose(overlay_element);
```

Comment: I'm also interested in doing something similar (albeit with python), did you figure out a way to make this work?